# Software for Respondent-Interactive Mass Data Collection and Verification?

Tags: windows, database, information-management, data, collection-manager

I work as a data consultant in a large hospital, and I need to collect faculty data in massive quantities. Here's my dilemma: many of the data fields that we are collecting are covered in one of our existing databases, i.e. Name, Address, Degree. However, we are adding 300+ fields of data for over 2500 individuals. Also, many cells of data are missing or out-dated. I'm looking for software to fill in those holes.

The idea, and hope, is to utilize software that allows respondents to view the data that we have for them so that they can either verify or edit the data that we already have for them.

This idea would be akin to surveygizmo's code merge, but with 10-20 times more custom fields. The big idea here is that we will be able to show respondents what data we have on them, and that respondents will be able to edit that data if it is missing, false or out-dated.

Someone has suggested Wufoo, but I am unsure if I will be able to individualize data for individuals for 300+ fields.

Comment: Any particular OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out by contacting surveygizmo.com's support staff (they're very lovely people, by the way.) I will leave this question open in case anyone is experiencing a similar situation in the future.

The answer is surveygizmo's HTTP Connect feature, which allows one to post or get data from an external database or spreadsheet. It is perfect for presenting a large number of pre-populated or empty fields to be filled, edited or verified by respondents.

The tutorial for this feature is here: http://help.surveygizmo.com/help/article/link/http-connect

Thanks to the community and to surveygizmo for having prompt response times and features!